# не получается выбрать номер ячейки в строке <tr>

Tags: javascript

```js
let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
let tr = tbody.querySelector('tr');
let td = tr.cellIndex;
console.log( td )
```

```html
  <table id="grid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-type="number">Возраст</th>
        <th data-type="string">Имя</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Вася</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Петя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Женя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Маша</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Илья</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cellIndex` - это свойство ячейки, а не строки.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableCellElement

```js
let tbody = document.querySelector('tbody');
let tr = tbody.querySelector('tr');
let tdIndex = tr.cells[1].cellIndex;
console.log( tdIndex )
```

```html
<table id="grid">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th data-type="number">Возраст</th>
        <th data-type="string">Имя</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>Вася</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Петя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>Женя</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>9</td>
        <td>Маша</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Илья</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```